# Android Launcher Application

Tags: android, android-viewpager, infinite-scroll, android-launcher

I'm trying to make a launcher application for android, just like Apex or Nova Launcher. I'm using `ViewPager` class to make the homescreen and the app drawer. Now, I want them(homescreen & app drawer) to scroll infinitely. For this purpose, I found a library called [LoopingViewPager](https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager) on GitHub. Again, I want to add some scroll effects(transitions) to the `ViewPager`, and for this purpose, I found another library on GitHub called [JazzyViewPager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager).

But, I **cannot** use these two libraries together since both of them extend the `ViewPager` class.

So, I want to know if there's any way to use both the libraries together. If not, then, Is there any method to fulfil the purpose of any one of the libraries manually?

Also, if there's any **open-source** library to make our own launcher application, please kindly give me the link.

Thanks in advance!!